# Calling a data frame object to set a variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains five numerical string variables. I need to convert these to integers, which I achieve by the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columns':[timecol, SPcol, PVcol, MVcol, Datarow]})
df = df.astype("int")
```

I want to use each one of these objects inside the data frame to set unique local variables.  I have tried several ways to do this and get either a KeyError or different variations of TypeError.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
newTimeCol = df[0]  // which relates to the 'timecol' element value in df
newSPCol = df[1]
...
newDataRow = df[4]
```

The reason for using a data frame in the first place was because it was the easiest and most efficient way I could find to convert the numerical string variables to integers.

Any ideas on how I can make this work, or avoid it entirely by converting a string containing '1' into the integer 1?

Comment: To convert a string into a number, use `int(number)`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for pandas here. Use plain Python:

```
newTimeCol = int(timecol)
newSPCol = int(SPcol)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked a charm :)